# Stop div from inheriting bootstrap div's width

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="col-md-9 offset-md-3">
     <div class="chatbot-botchat-user">
          <p>Sino ang magaakalang mahal kita?</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Basically `chatbot-botchat-user` is inheriting its width from `col-md-9` so it fills the entire div instead of conforming to the content:

[image]

As you can see there is a space on the left side of the text. What I want to happen is that the blue background color does not conform to the `col-md-9`'s width but to the content

This is my CSS code:

```
.chatbot-botchat-user {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
}

.chatbot-botchat-user, .chatbot-botchat {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you remove the bootstrap helper classes, and then just style the div to your liking?

Comment: It's default padding! Try adding padding:0

Comment: I copied everything from your question for testing and am not getting the problem you describe. There is something missing from your html or css to reproduce the problem. (bootstrap 3.3.7.)

Comment: @wazz I'm using bootstrap 4 :(

Answer (score 0):

In the `head` section of your HTML file, move your custom css file to down so that it is always below the bootstrap cdn link.

```
<head>
//Bootstrap CDN
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

//Your custom CSS file
<link rel="stylesheet type="text/css" href="path_to_css_file/style.css">
<head>
```

In this case, your code in your css file overwrites bootstrap code.

Good luck!